# How to get Max, Min value from Group Fields only hit in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, max, field

My Database like this:

```
hits:[
{"x1": 5, "x2": 6, "x3": 7, "x4": 8, "y1": 1, "y2": 2, "y3": 6, "y4": 5},
{"x1": 5, "x2": 6, "x3": 1, "x4": 8, "y1": 1, "y2": 2, "y3": 3, "y4": 5}]
```

First: I want get result max group `X(x1,x2,x3,x4)` - min group `X(x1,x2,x3,x4)`, max group `Y(y1, y2, y3, y4)` - min group `Y(y1, y2, y3, y4)` base on every hit,

like that:
hit 1st:

```
max groupX(5,6,7,8) = 8
min groupX(5,6,7,8) = 5
max groupY(1,2,6,5) = 6
min groupY(1,2,6,5) = 1
```

and expect every hit: `maxX - minX, maxY - minY so: (8-5), (6-1) = 3, 5`
Similar to hit 2nd. 
And total expect result:

```
3, 5   
7, 4
```

And continue, I want get max every column. so the end expect result like that:

```
7, 5.
```

So it in ElasticSearch, I still not yet how to work it.
Please give me a hand. Thank you very much. 
Sorry if I can not description problem is simple, because my qualification about english too bad.

So that, when query in ElasticSearch, I don't know how to get Max and Caculator like that. In sql, I can

```
SELECT MAX(T2.MaxX) AS MAXHEIGHT, MAX(T2.MaxY) AS MAXWIDTH
 FROM 
( 
   SELECT
 ( SELECT MAX(value.x) - MIN(value.x)
     FROM (VALUES 
     (x1),(x2),(x3),(x4)) AS value(x)) AS MaxX,
( SELECT MAX(value.y) - MIN(value.y)
    FROM (VALUES
     (y1),(y2),(y3),(y4)) AS value(y)) AS MaxY
 FROM (T1) T2
```

Comment: I was resolved it. I use script inline Grovy. I set turn on it in file setup elasticsearch.yml   script.inline: on. and use method get max(a, b). So I can group by in Aggration. So my code:

Comment: .Aggregations(maxX => maxX
                                                        .Max("MAXWIDTHDEFECT", m1 => m1.Script(scrip1 => scrip1.Inline("max(max(doc['cad_x_left_top'].value, doc['cad_x_left_bottom'].value),max(doc['cad_x_right_bottom'].value, doc['cad_x_right_top'].value)) - min(min(doc['cad_x_left_top'].value, doc['cad_x_left_bottom'].value),min(doc['cad_x_right_bottom'].value, doc['cad_x_right_top'].value))")))